# Excel VBA formula R1C1 Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the vlookup function in excel. by right formula is this:

```
    "=VLOOKUP([Engagement Id],Pivots!AL:AU,10,FALSE)"
```

When i do my vba, it changes to

```
    Range("CT2").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP([Engagement Id],Pivots!C[-60]:C[-51],10,FALSE)"
```

I dont want this -60:-51 and I want the letters itself. but once i change the formula to have AL: AU instead of -60 :-51 it doesnt work. Anyone knows what to do?

Adrian

Comment: Presumably you mean "When I'm recording a macro" - this is the default behavior for formulas when recording macros. If you don't want this then look at how to assign a formula to a cell using VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R1C1 formulas use indexed cell coordinates (numbers), if you want to use letters don't use R1C1 formula but classic ones:

`Range("CT2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP([Engagement Id],Pivots!AL:AU,10,FALSE)"`